# Combinaciones/parejas posibles en un mismo array

Tags: javascript, array, loops

Quiero emparejar entre si todos los elementos de un mismo array, pero un elemento no puede emparejarse con si mismo.

El código que he conseguido es el siguiente:

```
        function combine(list) {

        var pairs = new Array((list.length * (list.length - 1)) / 2),

        pos = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

            for (var j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {

                pairs[pos++] = [list[i], list[j]];

            }

        }

        return pairs;

        }

    var result = combine([1, 2, 3, 4]);
    console.log("Combinaciones = "+ JSON.stringify(result));
```

El resultado que espero como solución será:

```
Combinaciones = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,1],[2,3],[2,4],[3,1],[3,2],[3,4],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3]]
```

Sin embargo obtengo este y no sé dónde está el error:

```
Combinaciones = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]];
```

De tal manera que por ejemplo si comprueba el 1,2 también quiero que compruebe el 2,1 pero no cada número con si mismo.

**¿Cómo obtener las combinaciones de parejas posibles en ambos sentidos, tan solo omitiendo la de un número consigo mismo?**

Comment: j tienes que iniciarlo a 0, si lo inicias como i+1, cuando i vale 2, te empieza a comparar con el 3, no toma el 1, con lo cual no te puede generar el par [2,1] o el [3,2]

Comment: Tienes toda la razón! Que fallo, no lo veía... Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La variable j en el segundo bucle tendrías que inicializarla a 0 , porque si no te tomaría el valor dos cuando el primer bucle estuviese en la primera iteración.
Te quedaría así:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {

            pairs[pos++] = [list[i], list[j]];

        }

    }
```

Comment: Marcos, buen apunte el de colocar en la seccion de respuestas pero ese texto no es parte de la respuesta asi que lo quité. Sin embargo, no es obligatorio responder. Si se quiere dejar un comentario para no tener que explicarlo en una respuesta es valido aunque él se pierde la rep hehe Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Muchas gracias por la recomendación y por editar ese texto, simplemente era a modo de recordatorio haha. Un saludo